# How to balance classification using DecisionTreeClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a data set where the classes are unbalanced. The classes are either `0`, `1` or `2`.

How can I calculate the prediction error for each class and then re-balance `weights` accordingly in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to fully balance (treat each class as equally important) you can simply pass `class_weight='balanced'`, as it is stated in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html):

> The “balanced” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust
>   weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data
>   as `n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))`

Comment: Please note that it is a parameter of the classifier (the constructor), not of `fit`.

Comment: Note that using this will descalibrate your model.

Answer (score 10):

If the frequency of class A is 10% and the frequency of class B is 90%, then the class B will become the dominant class and your decision tree will become biased toward the classes that are dominant

In this case, you can pass a dic `{A:9,B:1}` to the model to specify the weight of each class, like

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight={A:9,B:1})
```

The `class_weight='balanced'` will also work, It just automatically adjusts weights according to the proportion of each class frequencies

[image]

After I use `class_weight='balanced'`, the record number of each class has become the same (around 88923)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class_weight, but it doesn't seem very good at dealing with heavily unbalanced classes. There are other methods:

I'm using binary classification as an example here...

Class 0 (Under-represented): Num records x

Class 1 (Over-represented): Num records y

Oversampling: If there are x records of the under-represented class, and y records of the over-represented class then you take all y, plus x repeated (y/x)

Undersampling: If there are x records of the under-represented class, and y records of the over-represented class then you take all x plus a y-sized sample of the over-represented class

There's also SMOTE which attempts to create synthetic records for the under-represented class: https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html